# Is there a way to use a higher version kubectl to request a lower version kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a `kubectl` which version is `1.8.0` and a kubernetes cluster which version is `1.7.4`. Using this `kubectl` to request the kubernetes cluster will be wrong for some cases like applying an `CronJob` yaml file.

I have searched a lot but could not find a way to use a higer version `kubectl` to request a lower version kubernetes cluster.

For Docker, I could set `DOCKER_API_VERSION` to be compatible with the server API for the docker client. So for kubernetes, is there a similar to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl apply` in particular has no ability to [switch versions of a resource](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16543#issuecomment-157091086) (it embeds a particular version in an annotation and must deal with that version forever).

For general fetching of resources, you can fully qualify the API group and version of resource you request from the server:

```
# no qualification, defaults to preferred server group and version
kubectl get deployments

# group qualification, defaults to preferred server version of that group
kubectl get deployments.extensions
kubectl get deployments.apps

# fully qualified resource.version.group
kubectl get deployments.v1beta1.extensions
kubectl get deployments.v1beta1.apps
kubectl get deployments.v1beta2.apps
```

Comment: Is this means that APIServer could support multiple versions of a resource?

Comment: yes. if you create a Deployment object in the extensions API group, you can request it via the apps API group and the server will perform the conversion for you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a option like that in my `kubectl` version 1.6.6.

`kubectl options`

`--api-version='': DEPRECATED: The API version to use when talking to the server`

It was **deprecated** though. I guess this option has been deleted in 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

IMO, simply install the lower version `kubectl`, use it with the lower version cluster.

`kubectl` is a single file application, we can have multiple versions co-exist.

```
curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.7.4/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl -o kubectl-1.7
```

Comment: It works but it seems not easy to use facing multiple versions of k8s 